# Solution or proof of provided solution for a Sturm Liouville Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I want to find a solution to the PDE
$$
(1-x^2)\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}
$$
With boundary conditions
$$
T(x=a) = T(x=-a) = 0\\ T'(x=0) = 0\\ T(y = 0) = 1
$$

I think this is solved by separation of variables like
$$
T(x,y) = X(x) \cdot Y(y)
$$
which leads to the Sturm Liouville Problem
$$
d/dx( X') + (\lambda (1-x^2))X = 0
$$

I found a source that claims the solution is of the form
$$
T(x,y) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (A_m e^{-\tilde\lambda_m^2 y} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{nm}x^n)
$$

Ideally someone could provide me a way to find this solution. But I'd be also happy to just find a simple way to proove correctness and calculate the coefficients.

**Edit:** I tried it on my own, but do not get the correct results. Here is what I tried:
Using a wolfram alpha solver, I got the solution, which is some parabolic cylinder function. I then expressed this solution as taylor series like
$$
X(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$$
To calculate the coefficients $A_m$ I applied the BC $T(y=0)=1$ which gives
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty A_m \cdot a_{nm} = \begin{cases}0 & k>0 \\ 1 & k = 0\end{cases}
$$

I tried to approximate the values by using a finite sum. But the solution seems quite unstable (the values $A_m$ for larger $m$ are very large with alternating sign).

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this solution and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Im pretty sure you're derivative B.C is overdetermining the system, why isn't having periodic BC's enough? Anyways, your resulting ODE for X is a parabolic cylinder equation, to which it is possible to compute coefficients. This leads me to believe that the second series may just be the taylor series expansion of X, and hence you have that weird looking double series.

Comment: You are correct, there are more BCs than needed since I was not sure which one will give me the easier solution. If I would calculate the coefficients from the parabolic cylinder equation and then make the Taylor series expansion of X, will this lead to the same result as I would get from a power series solution (expressing X as a Taylor series and then solving the ODE)?

Comment: You would get the same thing. The derivation of those functions is via series solutions, as you would find hermits polynomials and vessel functions. Something I did notice playing with numerical solutions was that with those boundary conditions, $X=0$ is only possible.